# Best software to draw in 3D

Tags: windows, drawing, 3d, vector-graphics, modeling

I'm trying to draw a picture like this; a 3D model and some inner parts. What is the best software to do that? I would appreciate if you could help me draw this.
I need a project so that I can add my own components.

[image]

Comment: There are many programs to do this. They let you create primary shapes, perform unions and substractions of volumes. What is your budget? Or do you want gratis, or open source?

Comment: Free software please.

Comment: You mean gratis, costs zero, right? "Free software" can mean "open source" as well.

Comment: Yes, costs zero!